# php artisan serve failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I have this error after running `php artisan serve`:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 
'/Users/toto/Sites/project/server.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
```

Here is my `index.php` in the project root folder

```
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

And here is the `.htaccess` in the project root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This may be due to permission issue, give permission to your project folder .

Comment: My project folder's permission is drwxrwxr-x .  www_:www_ and my user is in _www. I have no problem when I use my webserver, it happens only when I use `php artisan serv`

Comment: If you are using ubuntu type command in terminal-  sudo chmod -R 777 PATH TO YOUR PROJECT FOLDER.

Eg:- sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/mylaravelblog

Comment: I don't want to give full permission to my project folder !

Comment: That doesn't sound like a permission issue. `No such file or directory` tells you, that it can't find a file. Have you moved your project to another folder? Do you have the same issue with a fresh installed version of laravel?

Comment: I have rename server.php to index.php to redirect to public folder but the 'server.php' in the error is hardcoded.

Comment: I haven't the same issue with a fresh install.

Comment: But why you renamed it? The `server.php` is for laravel when using it via command line and normally you don't have to modify it. If you rename it laravel will crash, like it did, because it's searching for this file. You could point in your apache configuration to `/public` where the right `index.php` is located.

Comment: Pointing directly to the root folder is a really big security breach, because a hacker could point to `/.env` to read your configuration to gain access to your db.